# Dual-Boot UBUNTU and WINDOWS 7 - HELP

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows

Computer ask for Ubuntu Installation EVEN the machine has Ubuntu-14.04.4. and Windows 7 already installed. So, appears options to choose to Install or to Try Ubuntu just as the picture ([Options that I See When I Start the Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd7o5.jpg) ) AND, if I choose to install Ubuntu, and I see the partitions in installation, I see there is still Ubuntu and Windows in Machine. (look the screen picture I took) >> [Partition in disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGQtq.jpg)<<.
What can I do??? WILL I Re-install the ubuntu and it will repair the boot? Or I need to do other thing?

Comment: Try ejecting the DVD.

Comment: Yes. It was the first thing that came in my mind, but the DVD-drive is empty.

Comment: Try going into the BIOS boot menu and choosing GRUB, Linux, or Windows.

Comment: Will there be any problem if I re-install the ubuntu in the partition where the Ubuntu 14 is already installed?? I am using the ``try ubuntu`` version right now, for it is the only way to use the machine.

Comment: Nope, not a problem at all.  But you should be able to boot using the BIOS boot menu.

Comment: There was a MicroSD Card with Ubuntu Setup connected MicroSD Reader. Now it is normal!!!

Comment: Voting this to be close because this is a problem that can't be reproduced

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove all bootable media from devices.  This could include DVDs, SD cards, microSD cards, etc.  That way you cannot boot Ubuntu setup.

Thanks for confirming the microSD presence.  Please remove it and mark this answer accepted if it's right so that others can benefit from this question.

Moral of the story: Before you get turned on, check all the holes.